# Log4j2: How to append to HTML log using HtmlLayout

Tags: log4j2

I am creating html log files by using log4j2. When I am executing my code the first time the logs are formatted as a table. However, while executing a second time the data is not appended to the table, it is instead stored line by line under the table. Is there a way to append the logs to the existing table?

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="/home/developers/Desktop/exam/app-info.html"
                 filePattern="app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.html">
        <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8" title="Howtodoinjava Info Logs" locationInfo="true" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="10" modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.howtodoinjava" level="info" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
               <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

This is log file

[Screenshot of log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIY7a.png)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think the answer is that you can't do what you want with the `HtmlLayout` provided by log4j2. It looks like the `HtmlLayout` was intended to generate a single html file per execution.

If you take a look at the [source code for HtmlLayout](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=logging-log4j2.git;a=blob;f=log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/HtmlLayout.java;h=8a09e4aa3f90d074d9e0d6d82ffe3c7a79fcedd0;hb=HEAD), you'll see code like following:

```
@Override
public byte[] getHeader() {
    final StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
    append(sbuf, "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" ");
    ...
    appendLs(sbuf, "<html>");
    ...
    appendLs(sbuf, "<table ...");
    ...
    return sbuf.toString().getBytes(getCharset());
}

....

@Override
public byte[] getFooter() {
    final StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
    appendLs(sbuf, "</table>");
    appendLs(sbuf, "<br>");
    appendLs(sbuf, "</body></html>");
    return getBytes(sbuf.toString());
}
```

The code is clearly expecting to create a new html document each time as you can see the opening html tags in `getHeader` and closing tags in the `getFooter`.

You could [write your own layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Layouts) to do what you want but the problem you're going to face is determining when to write your footer. You don't want to write the footer until you're completely done with the file, so you will have to somehow implement a way to detect this situation (assuming you want to have clean HTML in your log).

If you don't care about having clean HTML then just don't write any footer. In this case you could simply copy the `HtmlLayout` class and change it slightly to create a new layout that does not write any footer. For example:

```
//your package and imports go here
...
@Plugin(name = "NoFooterHtmlLayout", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Layout.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public final class NoFooterHtmlLayout extends AbstractStringLayout {

    //Various other methods copied from HtmlLayout go here
    ...

    @Override
    public byte[] getFooter() {
        return new byte[0];
    }

    //Various other methods copied from HtmlLayout go here
    ...
}
```

and then in your log4j2 configuration you would use this:

```
<NoFooterHtmlLayout charset="UTF-8" title="My Title"
                locationInfo="true" />
```

Hope this helps!